# Javascript Delete matches in array

Tags: javascript

i want delete all matches in array, i have a function where i send a value, and through all matches in the array, and i delete if exist, but the array change for each `splice` , please look this is a litle example

```
var cars = ["Saab","Saab","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW","Volvo","Volvo", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW","Volvo"];

         for(j =0;j<cars.length;j++){                
                if(cars[j]=="Volvo"){
                  cars.splice(j, 1);
                }
         }
console.log(cars);
```

**the result**

```
["Saab", "Saab", "Saab", "BMW", "Volvo", "BMW", "BMW", "BMW"]
```

Comment: What if you inverse your task - create another array with only contents you need? It would be much easier. `var carsWithoutVolvo = cars.filter(function(car) { return car != 'Volvo'; });`

Comment: that sound good, but i need to know if i can find other solution

Comment: For what reason? Your solution is overcomplicated.

Answer (score 4):

Because indexes can get messed up when looping from beginning to end of an array and removing elements, usually it's best to go *backwards*:

```
var i = cars.length - 1;

while(i >= 0) {
  if(/* condition */) {
    cars.splice(i, 1);
  }

  i--;
}
```

I hate native loops though (no good reason, just a personal preference), so I prefer to use semantic `forEach/reduce/map/filter`.

`filter` is actually the most semantic here (next, maybe `reduce`):

```
var filteredCars = cars.filter(notVolvo);

function notVolvo(car) {
  return car !== 'Volvo';
}
```

If, for kicks and giggles, you wanted to use `reduce`, you could do:

```
var reducedCars = cars.reduce(notVolvo, []);

function notVolvo(aggregate, car) {
  return car === 'Volvo' ? aggregate : aggregate.concat([car]);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it start at `cars.length - 1`?

Comment: that work... thanks josh, I was looking for something like this, I do not like easy things xD!

Comment: "I do not like easy things" --- that's a silly argument

Comment: @zerkms if you always do the same things looking have the limited mind, what you propose is very simple and is the response of a beginner

Comment: @jearca after you get some experience you will eventually understand that the valuable solutions are the ones easy to read and maintain, not the tricky ones.

Comment: @JoshBeam ... unless you want to reserve a position in the company forever (then I would highly recommend to start using Haskell instead of JS)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, when you use `splice` to remove an item, following items will be moved one position backwards so that there is no gap.

However, your loop increases the index variable independently on whether an item was removed or not. That means that, when you delete an item, the next one will be skipped.

This can be fixed by counteracting the increment with a decrement:

```js
for (var i=0; i<cars.length; i++)
  if (cars[i] == "Volvo")
    cars.splice(i--, 1);
```